# Realteck ALC274 with a microphone array not working in Mint 21.2, with Intel HDA

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, realtek, microphone

I got a new windows based laptop and decided to install Mint (Mint 21.2 Cinnamon) on it. This laptop comes with a microphone array around its camera.

I got most of the hardware to work including built-in speakers, so some parts of the audio drivers are working.

The only thing is that the microphone array does not work... Mint cannot detect the microphone array or any other microphone connected to the side jack.

The array works fine when booting with Windows.

Where else should I look to resolve this?

[image: mint sound pic]

some tech details:

Mint 21.2 (Based of Ubuntu Jammy)

```
inxi -A

Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-84-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

```
dmesg | grep audio

[   66.531528] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: couldn't bind with audio component
[   66.587873] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC274: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   66.587890] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   66.587897] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   66.587902] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   66.587905] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   66.587908] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[  624.313215] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: hda-codec: reconfiguring
[  624.313218] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: The codec is being used, can't reconfigure.
```

```
pactl list sources

Source #1
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 25
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x603d1a0000 irq 198"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "51ca"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Answer (score 0):

I learnt from the mint forum that because the default Linux kernel (which comes with mint 21.2) is version 5.15, it was very likely not to contain drivers compatible with this new laptop hardware.

So as per their suggestion I went into the journey of upgrading it.

I followed the blog from [linuxcapable](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-latest-linux-kernel-on-linux-mint/) and installed the latest kernel version (6.5.5 as of writing).

I executed the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
reboot
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mainline -y
```

Then I opened the program

> Taskbar > Mainline Kernels

I selected version 6.5.5 and clicked on Install
[image: Mainline]]

once the new kernel was installed, I rebooted once more

After rebooting, the microphone Array started working without issues!